# How to connect to a node.js server from android?

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io

I am using the following code to communicate with a Node.js server through socket.io but I am unable to obtain a connection.

```
private Socket mSocket;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     try {
        mSocket = IO.socket("http://163.172.112.100:8443");
        Log.i("MainActivity: ", "Successfully connected!!!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("MainActivity: ", e.toString());
    }

    mSocket.connect();
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to obtain a connection with the server or a better android library for socket.io?

Comment: What is that catch telling you what you did not tell us yet?

Comment: `mSocket.connect();`. Place that in that try block too.